# Laravel routes not working in google app engine

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

```
runtime: php
 env: flex

 runtime_config:
 document_root: public

# Serve php scripts.
 handlers:
 url: /(.+\.php)$
 script: \1

  # Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
  skip_files:
 - .env

  `enter code here`env_variables:
 # Put production environment variables here.
   APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: base64:qWGpR2KHe2PDKbbFhetMC57fKef+P754VSRprZD4wmQ=

  APP_URL: ****
```

after deployment the url hits the / which is the root. any other route after the / is giving me 404. example /login /register is not working. Is there a way to configure the app.yaml to handle the routes. That is my app.yaml file.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.php` handler? That looks like it might interfere.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC i tried that but it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar difficulty trying to deploy my application on App engine. I will share with you how I fixed it.

- remove routes from api.php (I didn't need these for my application)
- enable cloud SQL api [enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https:%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.164522367.-1360075521.1510572080)
- Follow this tutorial [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)  **follow next two steps before deploying**
- make the following changes to the composer.json file. The tutorial is incorrect.
  ```
  "post-install-cmd": [
              "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
              "php artisan optimize",
              "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
          ]
  ```
- Configure your app.yaml file like so:
  ```
  runtime: php
  env: flex

  runtime_config:
    document_root: public

  env_variables:
    # Put production environment variables here.
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_LOG: errorlog
    APP_KEY: APP_KEY (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    CACHE_DRIVER: database
    SESSION_DRIVER: database
    ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
    DB_HOST: localhost
    DB_PORT: 3306
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
    DB_DATABASE: DATABASE_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_USERNAME: USERNAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)

    QUEUE_DRIVER: database

  beta_settings:
      # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
      # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
      cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
  ```

Comment: thanks i will take a look at it. the stress made me look  elsewhere to deploy my app. with this i'll take a look at it again.